# Word jumble game in phython

Tags: python

I'm trying to code a function that opens a text file in order to display a title but for some reason Python cannot find the text file even though it is in the same folder

I've tried changing names and creating new folders but I'm still getting the same result and the code needs to look something like this:

[this is the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgdh2.png)

[this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt7c8.png)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] - post code **as text**, not screenshots.

Comment: Are you sure that the 'text' file does not have an extension?

Comment: Please also show how you call your code. What's the working dir?

Comment: You're probably confused about your Python runtime's current working directory. Use an absolute path to your file

Answer (score 0):

The line :

```
fo = open("test")
```

gives the error : FileNotFoundError.
This is most likely due to the fact that there is no extension. Test is a text document which implies extension .txt. Instead, you should use

```
fo = open("test.txt")
```

You should make sure windows is showing extension in filename.

PS. It would also mean the real name of your python file is word jumble.py.py